# Dns сервера: рекурсивный запрос и нерекурсивный

Tags: dns

Какие dns сервера поддерживают рекурсивные запросы, а какие нет? В чем их отличие?

Comment: спасибо, но у меня задание написать какие dns поддерживают рекурсивный запрос,а какие нет, как быть)?

Comment: а гугл не помог? Я бы делал так. Вначале зашел на [wiki:DNS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dns), почитал, нашел список dns серверов (он конечно не полный, но можно погуглить). Потом прогуглил каждый на тему рекурсивности.

Answer (score 4):

При рекурсивном запросе Вы просто обращаетесь к серверу, а он, если не найдет у себя нужной записи, идет к другим серверам и спрашивает у них. Нерекурсивный dns сервер в данном случае просто говорит - "я не знаю, но спроси у этого сервера". И клиент будет слать ещё один запрос. Понятное дело, что при медленном интернете первый вариант лучше.

Bind, классический dns сервер поддерживает оба варианта и позволяет их тонко настраивать.